# Color gradient filling along a path

Tags: color, pstricks, gradient

I want to make the gradient color to follow the pipe curve below rather than to span from the left to the right.

The following MWE shows the default behavior which is not what I'm looking for.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-slpe} 

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(8,-7)
\pscustom[fillstyle=slope]{
  \psline(6,0)
  \psarcn(6,-2){2}{90}{-90}
  \psline(2,-4)
  \psarc(2,-5){1}{90}{-90}
  \psline(8,-6)
  \psline(8,-7)(2,-7)
  \psarcn(2,-5){2}{-90}{90}
  \psline(6,-3)
  \psarc(6,-2){1}{-90}{90}
  \psline(0,-1)
  \closepath}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

Could you help me to accomplish my objective?

**Update**

Using [Pierre's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181420/15874), here is what I ended up with:

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\makeatletter
 \pst@addfams{pst-HSB}
 \define@key[psset]{pst-HSB}{HueBegin}{%
   \def\PstParametricplotHSB@HueBegin{#1}}
 \define@key[psset]{pst-HSB}{HueEnd}{%
   \def\PstParametricplotHSB@HueEnd{#1}}
 \define@boolkey[psset]{pst-HSB}[Pst@]{HSB}[true]{}
 % Default values
 \psset[pst-HSB]{HueBegin = 0, HueEnd = 1, HSB = true}
 \psset{dimen = outer}

 \def\parametricplotHSB{\pst@object{parametricplotHSB}}
 \def\parametricplotHSB@i#1#2#3{{%
  \begin@ClosedObj
  \addto@pscode{%
    /t #1 def
    /dt #2 t sub \psk@plotpoints\space div def
    /t t dt sub def
    /Counter 0 def
    1 setlinejoin
    \psk@plotpoints {
      /t t dt add def
      /Counter Counter 1 add def
      #3
      \pst@number\psyunit mul exch
      \pst@number\psxunit mul exch
      1 Counter eq { moveto currentpoint /OldY ED /OldX ED }
        {\ifPst@HSB
          /PointY exch def
          /PointX exch def
          Counter \psk@plotpoints\space div
          \PstParametricplotHSB@HueEnd\space
          \PstParametricplotHSB@HueBegin\space sub mul
          \PstParametricplotHSB@HueBegin\space add
          1 1 sethsbcolor
          OldX OldY PointX PointY lineto lineto 
          stroke
          PointX PointY moveto
      /OldX PointX def /OldY PointY def
        \else lineto \fi } ifelse
     } repeat }%
   \end@ClosedObj}
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5)(4.5,4.5)
 \psset{
   linewidth = 1cm,
   plotpoints = 300
 }
  \parametricplotHSB[
    HueBegin = 0.70,
    HueEnd   = 0.66
  ]{3.05}{0}{t 4}
  \parametricplotHSB[
    HueBegin = 0.70,
    HueEnd   = 0.78
  ]{0}{180}{t sin 3 add t cos 3 add}
  \parametricplotHSB[
    HueBegin = 0.78,
    HueEnd   = 0.86
  ]{3.05}{0.95}{t 2}
  \parametricplotHSB[
    HueBegin = 0.86,
    HueEnd   = 0.92
  ]{0}{-180}{t sin 1 add t cos 1 add}
  \parametricplotHSB[
    HueBegin = 0.92,
    HueEnd   = 1
  ]{0.95}{4}{t 0}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

**Update 2**

I've not managed to get vertical ends on the curve and a black boundry; can anyone help with this?

**Update 3**

I've now found http://pstricks.blogspot.dk/2015/10/helice-tournant-autour-de-son-axe-et.html; can a similar coloring as alone the helix be obtained?

Comment: @StiffJokes I don't think so (but maybe I'm using it in the wrong place). If this problem is solved, I still can't figure out how to get a smooth colour gradient throughout the entire pipe (with `slopebegin = {rgb:orange,0;black,100}, slopeend = {rgb:orange,80;black,20},`).

Comment: @StiffJokes Yes. The black end should have the colour `{rgb:orange,0;black,100}` (i.e., black, as it is now) and the other end (where the pipe is coming out of the furnace and the lower right part of it) should have the colour `{rgb:orange,80;black,20}`.

Comment: @StiffJokes I have come to the same conclusion. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: draw a line instead of rectangles, use the optional argument of `linearc` and have a look at http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Colors/colors#contColor

Comment: @Herbert I have now looked at the examples on the PSTricks page and I can't really figure out how to use it. Can I make you give an answer?

Comment: It might be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146487/19356

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've tried to follow everyone's advices,

- I have drawn 3 lines and 2 half-circles (instead of a shape)
- I've used the `\parametricplotHSB` to have the gradient

and here's what I got  :

```
    \documentclass[xcolor]{article}  
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-xkey}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Essai de Manuel Luque 19 février 2003
    % transformé par Denis Girou le 25 février 2003
    % révisé le 9 mai 2007
    % modifié par Pierre Vivegnis le 2 juin 2014
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \makeatletter
    \pst@addfams{pst-plothsb}

    \define@key[psset]{pst-plothsb}{HueBegin}{% Between 0 and 1
    \edef\PstParametricplotHSB@HueBegin{#1}}

    \define@key[psset]{pst-plothsb}{HueEnd}{% Between 0 and 1
    \edef\PstParametricplotHSB@HueEnd{#1}}

    \newif\ifPst@HSB
    \define@key[psset]{pst-plothsb}{HSB}[true]{\@nameuse{Pst@HSB#1}}

    % Default values
    \psset{HueBegin=0,HueEnd=1,HSB=true}

    \def\parametricplotHSB{\pst@object{parametricplotHSB}}
    \def\parametricplotHSB@i{\@ifnextchar[{\parametricplotHSB@do}{\parametricplotHSB@do[]}}
    \def\parametricplotHSB@do[#1]#2#3#4{{%
    \psset{#1}%
    \begin@ClosedObj
    \addto@pscode{%
    /t  #2 def
    /dt #3 t sub \psk@plotpoints\space div def
    /t t dt sub def
    /Counter 0 def
    \psk@plotpoints {
      /t t dt add def
      /Counter Counter 1 add def
    /F@pstplot \ifPst@algebraic (#4)
                        tx@AlgToPs begin AlgToPs end cvx
                     \else { #4 } 
              \fi  
       def
    \ifPst@algebraic 
       F@pstplot
        \else  #4  
    \fi 
      \pst@number\psyunit mul exch
      \pst@number\psxunit mul exch
      1 Counter eq
        {moveto}                    % First point
        {\ifPst@HSB                 % Other points than the first one
           /PointY exch def
           /PointX exch def
           Counter \psk@plotpoints\space div
               \PstParametricplotHSB@HueEnd\space
                 \PstParametricplotHSB@HueBegin\space sub mul
               \PstParametricplotHSB@HueBegin\space add
             1 1 sethsbcolor
           PointX PointY lineto
           stroke
           PointX PointY moveto
         \else
           lineto
         \fi} ifelse
        } repeat}% fin du code ps
    \end@ClosedObj}} % fin de la commande PSTricks

    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
        \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1, -1)(5,5)
          \psset{plotpoints=360, linewidth=10mm}%, HSB=false}%
            \parametricplotHSB[HueBegin=0,HueEnd=0.2]{-0.5}{3.01}{t 4}
            \parametricplotHSB[HueBegin=0.2,HueEnd=0.4]{0}{181}{t sin 3 add t cos 3 add}
            \parametricplotHSB[HueBegin=1,HueEnd=0.8]{4.5}{0.99}{t 0}
            \parametricplotHSB[HueBegin=0.8,HueEnd=0.6]{-180}{0}{t sin 1 add t cos 1 add}
            \parametricplotHSB[HueBegin=0.4,HueEnd=0.6]{3}{0.95}{t 2}
        \end{pspicture}
    \end{document}
```

and I gives me that : 
[image]

But I can't figure out how, when you add, the `HSB=false` option, manage the colours...

I hope my answer doesn't come too late... After 6 months `:P`

### plotpoints

I tried increasing the number of plotted points, but this was the best...
For that I can't help you, sorry...

Comment: This looks very nice! I'm gonna take a look at it later today. Thank you very much.

Comment: A good idea: Create a fully compilable example. Then others will find it easier to use the code when they search the page.

Comment: An extra question: How do I get vertical ends and surround the path with a black curve as in the initial example?

Comment: I have a solution, but it's not quite accurate...

Invert the begining and the end of the 2 horizontal lines (and thus the `HueBegin` and the `HueEnd`...
But it's a crappy way, I'm sure there is a better way...
Sorry...

Comment: Any change I can make you show me how to do it by updating your already excellent answer? `:)`

Comment: See my edited answer...