# Color gradient for \psline in PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I'd like to produce a `\psline` (or, even better, `\pscurve`) in PSTricks that has a color gradient.  I can't find a package that allows me to do so.  Is there one?  (`pst-slpe` produces sophisticated gradients for areas, but not, as far as I can see, for lines.)

(On the page https://comp.text.tex.narkive.com/tjLnOyJ4/applying-a-gradient-color-to-a-line Werner reports that he had asked the same question on the PSTricks mailing list in 2003 and received a response from Manuel Luque with the definition of a (complicated) function to create a parametric plot with a color gradient.  It doesn't seem easy to adapt that code to `\psline`.)

Comment: psline is a thin wrapper around the postscript lineto which can't (as far as I know) modify the color along the stroke so somewhere you are going to need to replace a single lineto by a paramaterised function plotting points of different colours so the answer you link to might be the best answer there is.

Comment: Related: [Path following color gradient in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141378/5764)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the pointer.  As far as I can see, the most recent version of the `\parametricplotHSB` code is at http://pstricks.blogspot.com/2011/09/vos-courbes-aux-couleurs-de-larc-en.html.  It appears not to be included in any package.

Comment: A `\pslineHSB` macro has been written at some point (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406413/varying-the-color-along-pstricks-lines-circles-etc/ for a demo that contains not only a plot but also two lines with a gradient) but I could not find the code for this macro anywhere. I did find a subsection about `\pslineHSB` in the docs of `pst-hsb` at https://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/source/pst-hsb/ but the code itself does not seem to be there.

Comment: @Marijn Good sleuthing!  Presumably `\pslineHSB` uses `\parametricplotHSB` along the lines of `\def\pslineHSB(#1,#2)(#3,#4){\parametricplotHSB{#1}{#3}{t t #1 sub #4 #2 sub #3 #1 sub div mul #2 add}}`.  That needs to be developed to handle vertical lines and allow for an optional argument, but those modifications seem easy.  I guess one could do the same thing for `\pscurve`, although it seems that that would be much more difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-hsb}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.75,-0.75)(11,5)
% \psgrid(0,-4)(10,4)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(11,5)   
\pslineHSB[linewidth=1mm,HueBegin=0,HueEnd=0.5](0,0)(10,1) 
\pslineHSB[linewidth=1mm,HueBegin=0.5,HueEnd=0.7](0,1)(10,3) 
\pslineHSB[linewidth=1mm,HueBegin=0.8,HueEnd=1](0,2)(10,5) 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or only for two given colors. Maybe that it will be part of an update of PSTricks ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\makeatletter
\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{startColor}[black]{%
  \colorlet{tempcolor}[rgb]{#1}%   we need rgb
  \pst@getcolor{tempcolor}\ps@startColor}
\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{endColor}[white]{%
  \colorlet{tempcolor}[rgb]{#1}%
  \pst@getcolor{tempcolor}\ps@endColor}
\psset[pstricks]{startColor=black,endColor=white}

\def\pscolorLine{\def\pst@par{}\pst@object{pscolorLine}}
\def\pscolorLine@i{%
  \pst@getarrows{%
    \begin@OpenObj
    \pscolorLine@ii}}
    
\def\pscolorLine@ii(#1){\@ifnextchar({\pscolorLine@iii(#1)}{\pscolorLine@iii(0,0)(#1)}}%

\def\pscolorLine@iii(#1,#2)(#3,#4){%
  \use@par
  \ifx\psk@arrowA\@empty\else\psline[linecolor=\ps@startColor]{->}(!#3 0.5 mul #4 0.5 mul)(#1,#2)\fi
  \ifx\psk@arrowB\@empty\else\psline[linecolor=\ps@endColor]{->}(!#1 0.5 mul #2 0.5 mul)(#3,#4)\fi
  \pst@getcoor{#1,#2}\pst@tempA
  \pst@getcoor{#3,#4}\pst@tempB
  \addto@pscode{
    10 dict begin
    [ \psgetRGBColorValues{\ps@startColor} ] dup == aload length 1 eq { dup dup } if 
      3 copy 3 array astore /startColor ED
    [ \psgetRGBColorValues{\ps@endColor} ] dup == aload length 1 eq { dup dup } if 
      3 copy 3 array astore /endColor ED
%   on stack R1 G1 B1 R2 G2 B2 
    4 -1 roll               % R1 G1 R2 G2 B2 B1
    sub 256 div /dB ED      % R1 G1 R2 G2 
    3 -1 roll               % R1 R2 G2 G1 
    sub 256 div /dG ED      % R1 R2 
    exch sub 256 div /dR ED
    \pst@tempB /Y2 ED /X2 ED 
    \pst@tempA /Y1 ED /X1 ED 
    Y2 Y1 sub X2 X1 sub atan /Angle ED
    Y2 Y1 sub Angle sin dup 0 eq { pop }{ div } ifelse /L_line ED     % line length
    \ifx\psk@arrowA\@empty\else 
      X2 X1 sub L_line div \psk@arrowlength\space mul \pst@number\psxunit mul X1 add /X1 ED
      Y2 Y1 sub L_line div \psk@arrowlength\space mul \pst@number\psyunit mul Y1 add /Y1 ED
     \fi
    \ifx\psk@arrowB\@empty\else 
      X2 X1 sub L_line div \psk@arrowlength\space mul \pst@number\psxunit mul X2 exch sub /X2 ED
      Y2 Y1 sub L_line div \psk@arrowlength\space mul \pst@number\psyunit mul Y2 exch sub /Y2 ED
     \fi
    Y2 Y1 sub 256 div /dY ED
    X2 X1 sub 256 div /dX ED
%    dR dG dB == == ==
%startColor == endColor ==
    \ifPst@noCurrentPoint\else\pst@cp\fi      % current point?
    0 1 255 {      
      /dIndex ED
%startColor == 
      X1 Y1 moveto
      X1 dX add  Y1 dY add % start for coordinate array
      gsave
      lineto
      CP /Y1 ED /X1 ED
      \pst@number\pslinewidth SLW
      startColor aload pop 3 copy setrgbcolor
      % on stack r g b
      dB add 3 1 roll    % b+dB r g 
      dG add 3 1 roll    % b+dB g+dG r
      dR add 3 1 roll    % b+dB g+dG r+dR
      3 array astore /startColor ED
      stroke
      grestore
    } for 
    end
  }%
  \end@OpenObj
  \ignorespaces
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[linewidth=12pt,showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscolorLine(0,-5)(0,5)
\pscolorLine[startColor=cyan,endColor=magenta](-5,0)(5,0)
\pscolorLine[startColor=blue,endColor=green]{->}(-5,5)(5,-5)
\pscolorLine[startColor=red,endColor=blue]{<->}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `texdoc pst-hsb` will open `t-ghsb.pdf` that contains only a single page with two rectangles.

Comment: It does not even compile (TL-2021) :-( `! LaTeX Error: File pst-hsb.sty not found.`

Comment: But apparently user187802 has the source package available (the wrapper package `pst-hsb.sty` and the actual code in `pst-hsb.tex`), maybe this can be shared somewhere (possibly even by copying the full code of `pst-hsb.tex` in this answer if it is not too long)?

Comment: I completely forget that it is not on CTAN. I'll upload it as soon as possible. Until then it is here: https://hvoss.org/pst-hsb.zip

Comment: What does "Run with `lualatex`" mean?

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne `lualatex` is one of the various LaTeX compilers, i.e., the name of the program that you type in the terminal/command prompt to run LaTeX (so here `lualatex nameofyourfile.tex` [enter]), or if you don't use the terminal then it is one of the options that is listed in your editor somewhere in a menu or toolbar. Recent versions of LuaLaTeX have the advantage that they can compile (a subset of) PSTricks code and also produce pdf output, whereas before you needed to compile with `latex` and then run `dvips` and `ps2pdf` on the respective output files.

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne: With `lualatex` you do not need GhostScript, you'll get directly a pdf

Comment: This solution (much!) more than serves my purpose, and I have accepted the answer.  However, for others looking for `\psline`s with color gradients, note that the gradients possible with `pst-hsb.sty` are, if I understand correctly, limited to segments of the rainbow.  For example, I don't think you can go from red to green without passing through yellow.  (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne: You are right, at the moment only colours in hub model. But another one should be no problem. Let's see what I can do ...

Comment: I think something might be slightly off in the calculations: if I add `\pslineHSB[linewidth=1mm,HueBegin=0,HueEnd=0.5](1,2)(2,1)` after the first `\pslineHSB` in your example, I get a line from (2,1) to (3,0), and if I add a `\pslineHSB` with the same value of the x coordinate for both points (e.g. (2,1),(2,3)) I seem not to get any line at all.

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne: see edited answer

Comment: Thank you --- that's terrific!  I broke my right wrist today, so it's hard for me to work on the computer, but as soon as I can I'll try it out.

Comment: IMHO pst-hsb does only a part of the job: it's called *hsb* but only offers control for the first parameter (hue). Additional parameters such as SaturationBegin, BrightnessBegin, etc. would make it more interesting. I've searched for ways to get a \psarc with arrows at the ends and gradient filling with two arbitrary colors, but it seems that no pst-* package allows for that…

Comment: That's simple to implement ... will do in the next few days

Comment: Hi there,
is there a possibility to add the linewidth as a parameter that can be changed for a line? Something like WidthBegin and WidthEnd? I am looking for such possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

While you are waiting for PStricks help, here is my attempt at a [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) solution, for comparison.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef cgdraw(expr P, a, b) = 
    save s, n; 
    numeric s, n;
    4s = xpart urcorner currentpen - xpart llcorner currentpen;
    n = arclength P / s;
    for i=0 upto n:
        draw point arctime s * i of P of P withcolor (i/n)[a, b];
    endfor
enddef;
beginfig(1);
    path p; p = origin .. (89, 34) .. (144, -13) .. (200, 0);
    cgdraw(p, red, blue);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped in `luamplib`, so please compile it with `lualatex`.

It works simply by drawing dots along the path.  You can use the same approach to taper the width of the line, for example by changing the line in the loop to

```
draw point arctime s * i of P of P withpen currentpen scaled (1-i/n);
```

which would give you this

[image]

- Note that `draw` with a single point in MP just draws a dot at the point using the current pen.  (Same as `drawdot`).

Comment: That's impressive ... I have not tried Metapost, but maybe I should!